# how to make PostgreSQL-13 slave node as read-write once primary node is down

Tags: replication, high-availability

I have two servers in master-slave configuration format. They are in streaming state and synchronization state is "Sync".

I also used "repmgr" to make them as a cluster in primary and standby mode and once primary is down standby becomes primary, which is fine.

The issue is when I make primary server down the backup server comes up but in Read-only mode due to which I am unable to write to the backup server.

Kindly let me know what config should be performed to make the secondary/slave server work in read-write mode once primary server is down.

Regards,
Diwakar Sharma

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact config for repmgr its hard to say exactly what's missing but have you configured a witness and configured automatic failover? These resources may help point you in the right direction.

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/how-to-automate-postgresql-12-replication-and-failover-with-repmgr-part-2/
https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-implement-repmgr-postgresql-automatic-failover
https://repmgr.org/docs/repmgr.html#PROMOTING-STANDBY

HTH.